# Django form saves only the last row, times the number of records in the form

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have a form which saves data. The problem is, only the last row of the form gets saved, multiplied by the number of records that appear in the form.

I have a feeling that only the last data row is being passed, and it is being looped through. However, for the life of me, I just cannot figure this out. Thanks in advance for help.

Here is the relevant code:

Model:

```
class MonthlySheet(models.Model):
employeename = models.ForeignKey(Employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='monthlysheets')
uan = models.CharField(max_length=12)
ip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
epfowages = models.IntegerField()
esicwages = models.IntegerField()
twelve_percent = models.IntegerField()
eight_three_three_percent = models.IntegerField()
difference = models.IntegerField()
working_days = models.IntegerField()
ncp = models.IntegerField()
zero_point_seven_five_percent = models.IntegerField()
```

Form:

```
class MonthlySheetForm(forms.Form):
print("Starting monthlysheetform class validation")
employeename_id = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
establishmentid = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
uan=forms.CharField(required=True)
ip=forms.CharField(required=True)
epfowages = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
esicwages = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
twelve_percent = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
eight_three_three_percent = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
difference = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
working_days = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
ncp = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
zero_point_seven_five_percent = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

def clean(self):
    print("Cleanse starting in MonthlySheetForm")
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    epfowages = cleaned_data.get('epfowages')
    esicwages = cleaned_data.get('esicwages')
    establishmentid = cleaned_data.get('establishmentid')
    employeename_id = cleaned_data.get('employeename_id')

    return cleaned_data
```

View:

```
def add_monthlysheet(request):
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
establishments = Establishment.objects.all()
employees = []
establishmentname = request.session.get('establishmentname', '')
establishment_id = ''  # Set initial value for establishment_id

monthlysheet = MonthlySheet.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    establishment_id = request.POST.get('establishmentname')
    establishment = Establishment.objects.get(id=establishment_id)
    employeename_id = request.POST.getlist('employeename_id')
    employees = Employees.objects.filter(establishmentname=establishment)
    request.session['establishmentname'] = establishment.name

    form = MonthlySheetForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        for i, employeename in enumerate(employeename_id):
            monthly_sheet = MonthlySheet(
                employeename_id=employeename,
                uan=form.cleaned_data.get('uan'),
                ip=form.cleaned_data.get('ip'),
                epfowages=form.cleaned_data.get('epfowages'),
                esicwages=form.cleaned_data.get('esicwages'),
                twelve_percent=form.cleaned_data.get('twelve_percent'),
                eight_three_three_percent=form.cleaned_data.get('eight_three_three_percent'),
                difference=form.cleaned_data.get('difference'),
                working_days=form.cleaned_data.get('working_days'),
                ncp=form.cleaned_data.get('ncp'),
                zero_point_seven_five_percent=form.cleaned_data.get('zero_point_seven_five_percent'),
            )

            # Print the fields in the current row
            print(i+1, employeename, monthly_sheet.uan, monthly_sheet.ip, monthly_sheet.epfowages,
              monthly_sheet.esicwages, monthly_sheet.twelve_percent, monthly_sheet.eight_three_three_percent,
              monthly_sheet.difference, monthly_sheet.working_days, monthly_sheet.ncp,
              monthly_sheet.zero_point_seven_five_percent)

            monthly_sheet.save()
    else:
        print(form.errors)
else:
    form = MonthlySheetForm()


context = {
    'establishments': establishments,
    'employees': employees,
    'monthlysheet': monthlysheet,
    'title': 'Add Monthly Sheet',
    'month': month,
    'year': year,
    'workingdays': workingdays,
    'establishmentname': establishmentname,
    'establishmentid': establishment_id,
    'form': form,
}

return render(request, 'app/add-monthlysheet.html', context=context)
```

add-monthlysheet.html:

```
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add-monthlysheet' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="establishmentname">Establishment Name:</label>
            <select name="establishmentname" id="establishmentname">
                {% for establishment in establishments %}
                <option value="{{ establishment.id }}">{{ establishment.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Show Employees</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="monthlysheet_fixed_values">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="month">Month:</label>
                    {{ month }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="year">Year:</label>
                    {{ year }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label class="workeddays-input" for="workeddays">Total WD:</label>
                    {{ workingdays }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="custom-seperator-small">

                <h2>{{ establishmentname }}</h2>
                <input type="hidden" name="establishmentid" value="{{ establishmentid }}">
                {{ establishmentid }}
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <hr class="my-4 border-top border-primary">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="cell">ID</th>
                        <th class="cell">Name</th>
                        <th class="cell">UAN</th>
                        <th class="cell">IP</th>
                        <th class="cell">EPFO Wages</th>
                        <th class="cell">ESIC Wages</th>
                        <th class="cell">12%</th>
                        <th class="cell">8.33%</th>
                        <th class="cell">Difference</th>
                        <th class="cell">Worked</th>
                        <th class="cell">NCP</th>
                        <th class="cell">0.75%</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for employee in employees %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="number" name="employeename_id" value="{{ employee.id }}" class="form-control employeename_id-input" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}" readonly></td>
                        <td>{{ employee.employeename }}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="uan" value="{{ employee.uan }}" class="form-control uan-input" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="ip" value="{{ employee.ip }}" class="form-control ip-input" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="epfowages" value="{{ employee.epfowages }}" class="form-control epfowages-input" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="esicwages" value="{{ employee.esicwages }}" class="form-control esicwages-input" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="twelve_percent" value="{{ employee.twelve_percent }}" class="form-control twelve-percent-input" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="eight_three_three_percent" value="{{ employee.eight_three_three_percent }}" class="form-control" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="difference" value="{{ employee.difference }}" class="form-control" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="working_days" value="{{ employee.working_days }}" class="form-control" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="ncp" value="{{ employee.ncp }}" class="form-control" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="zero_point_seven_five_percent" value="{{ employee.zero_point_seven_five_percent }}" class="form-control" data-employee-id="{{ employee.id }}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit-monthlysheet-data">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Output received:

1. 4 158745985633 6111547896216 222 222 27 19 8 22 0 2
2. 5 158745985633 6111547896216 222 222 27 19 8 22 0 2